# execption notifier gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, exception-notifier

I installed `exception_notifier` gem following this `http://railscasts.com/episodes/104-exception-notifications-revised`. But when running `rails s`, I got this

```
/home/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (NoMethodError)
```

So I tried to Google this problem, and I found that I could use in my `production.rb` file this `config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier::Rack...` insted of this `config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier...`

But then I got this message:

```
uninitialized constant ExceptionNotifier::Rack (NameError)
```

How should I handle this gem installation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the link `https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification` indicated by @pdobb, you 'll find you have to use

```
ExceptionNotification::Rack
```

instead of

```
ExceptionNotifier::Rack
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `ExceptionNotification::Rack`. `ExceptionNotifier` was for the pre-4.0 versions. See the Getting Started info here: https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification for the specifics.